# Modifying the !new marking on listitems or alternatives

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, list-item

I am looking for a way to increase the duration an item is marked as "new" in a list by up to 30 days.

I found this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287681.aspx), but it is only viable for Sp2007 and I can't find information, if this is applicable to the whole web applicaiton, site collection oder even a single list.

As an alternative I am imagining some sort of conditional formatting, to show the user if he has already opened the listitem. Is there a property which I could use to achieve this?

To break it down: I am looking for a way, to show a user new list entries (unread or up to 30 days old) on a rarely visited site collection, where peripheral information is gathered.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you have supplied states that you can enter a url to a Web Application, so if not you do not enter a URL it will be Farm wide, otherwise Web Application scope.

Controlling it on a lower level (site collection, web, list, etc.) is not possible with the command. For doing it on a single list, you could probably use XSL.

The `stsadm` command `stsadm -o setproperty -pn days-to-show-new-icon -pv 14` is valid for 2010 as well.